# Undirected graph and cities power sources path

Tags: algorithm, graph, computation-theory, breadth-first-search

I have a question regarding this problem:

Given *n* cities *C1,C2,...,Cn*:

1. The cost of constructing a power station at city *Ci* is *pi*.
2. Constructing an undirected power line between cities *Ci* and *Cj* costs *w_ij*.

Given all costs *pi, w_ij*, desing a polynomial time algorithm to find the minimum cost set of power supply path that connect *Ci* to another city with a power station.

Do you have any idea how can I attack this problem?

I've been thinking something like dynamic programming, and also something like "if city Ci doesn't have a power station, then it needs a connection to another city, so we can find for all j which *wi_j* is the smallest", but I'm not quite clear how to proceed from this point forward.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to have enough information.  How much power can a power station deliver?  Where are the existing power stations?

Answer (score 2):

We can think of constructing a power station at city Ci as choosing an edge of weight pi that connects Ci with a "Source of all power" node.

Your problem now reduces to finding the cheapest way of connecting all of the nodes (1 node for each city plus 1 node for the new "Source of all power").  This is a standard problem known as the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).